# Compression algorithm for a bit stream

Tags: stream, compression, bit

I am looking for a good algorithm for bit stream compression (packet payload compression).
I would like to avoid algorithms that are based on symbol probability. I have already tried the LZ family algorithms, and found none of them useful, even with BWT.

I am trying to accomplish a minimum compression percentage of 30%, but have only managed 3-5% using RLE.

What is a good algorithm that has a compression above 30%?

Comment: What is the nature of the data being compressed?  Is it audio or video data?

Comment: I want to compress packet payload (headers stay uncompressed) then send it over the network. the reciever then decompress the payload. so far every algorithm I try results in expansion of size.

Comment: You need to provide much more information on the data, and why you think it is compressible.

Comment: My aim is to compress all kinds of packets (http, smtp, tcp, udp, icmp, ...) that travel through a network using FPGA, so I need to find a good compression algorithm first but non works so far. and if we can compress a bit stream on the HD (there maybe some uncompressable) why not on the network, think of it like another "exe" file.

Comment: I just tried byte pair encoding, I got 2-20% compression.

Comment: @BioHazard Did you find a solution for this question? I also trying to do something similar to your idea.

Comment: I'm sorry but no I haven't

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv-Welch might work. I use a 16byte variation which reduces filesize of html to like 40% of its original

Answer (score 4):

If you have no knowledge about your input data, it's hard to achieve good compression (just like a general purpose compressor).

But at least you can try some context-based model. use several prefix bits as context and predict the probability of next bit, then pass the probability to a range coder.

Further compression can be achieved with a context mixing model without byte-alignment. see http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_43.